# NPM missing script build

Tags: reactjs, github, npm

```js
{
  "homepage": "https://github.com/neqts/RWeb.git",
  "name": "react-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run-script build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

`CMD:npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ttopo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-20T07_58_40_339Z-debug.log`

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program  Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli    'run', 1 verbose cli   'deploy' 1 verbose cli ] 2 info using    npm@6.14.8 3 info using node@v14.14.0 4 verbose run-script [    'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ] 5 info lifecycle    react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: react-website@0.1.0 6 verbose    lifecycle react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle    true 7 verbose lifecycle react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH:    C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\react2\react-website\node_modules.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program    Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program    Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft    SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL    Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program    Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ttopo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\ttopo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ttopo\AppData\Roaming\npm 8 verbose lifecycle   react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: C:\react2\react-website 9 silly  lifecycle react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm    run-script build' ] 10 silly lifecycle react-website@0.1.0~predeploy:    Returned: code: 1  signal: null 11 info lifecycle    react-website@0.1.0~predeploy: Failed to exec predeploy script 12    verbose stack Error: react-website@0.1.0 predeploy: `npm run-script    build` 12 verbose stack Exit status 1 12 verbose stack     at    EventEmitter. (C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16) 12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20) 12    verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14) 12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20) 12    verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)  12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit    (internal/child_process.js:288:5) 13 verbose pkgid    react-website@0.1.0 14 verbose cwd C:\react2\react-website 15 verbose    Windows_NT 10.0.19041 16 verbose argv "C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy" 17 verbose node v14.14.0 18 verbose npm  v6.14.8 19 error code    ELIFECYCLE 20 error errno 1 21 error react-website@0.1.0 predeploy:  `npm run-script build` 21 error Exit status 1 22 error Failed at the react-website@0.1.0 predeploy script. 22 error This is probably not a    problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 23    verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I try to put my react application on the server, but when starting npm run build a myth pops up like an error someone has an idea what I am doing wrong if I ask for help, I am grateful for your time

Comment: Check the `scripts` field in the package.json, it seems like you're missing the "build" command declaration there. If the project is created using `create-react-app`, try adding this: `"build": "react-scripts build"` and running again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error say that the build script is missing, so please add the below definition to your **script** config settings.

```
"build": "react-scripts build"
```